# Iterate value dynamically

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

I'm using the below query to calculate a budget value dynamically means iterating upto selected date value.

```
SUM(case when Name = 'Budget' then  Value + ((Value/@TotaldaysinMonth) * 
@DaysPastinMonth) end) as [Budget]
```

Here variable `@DaysPastinMonth` should be dynamic. Means if I select a date as `03/31/2017`. Then the query should run upto the previous month value. Another example is if I select August, then I need to run query from Jan-Aug.

`For Jan`

```
SUM(case when Name = 'Budget' then  Value + ((Value/@TotaldaysinMonth) * 
@DaysPastinJanMonth) end) as [Budget]
```

`For Feb`

```
SUM(case when Name = 'Budget' then  Value + ((Value/@TotaldaysinMonth) * 
@DaysPastinFebMonth) end) as [Budget]
```

`For Mar`

```
SUM(case when Name = 'Budget' then  Value + ((Value/@TotaldaysinMonth) * 
@DaysPastinMarMonth) end) as [Budget]
```

Also I have created variables for all the 12 months which holds DaysPastinMonth.

Can anyone suggest how this can be achieved using case statement.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Show input and output data.

Comment: So if the date is 4 Jan 2017, what is the value for `@DaysPastinMonth`?

Comment: I think you should post sample data and show expected output. So everybody can help easily.

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking about this in loop when you could do it with set based operations.

```
----------------------------------------------------------
--Create a table of dates for testing
----------------------------------------------------------
if object_id('tempdb..#dates') is not null 
drop table #dates

create table #dates(d date
                    ,RN bigint)

declare @sdate datetime='2017-01-01 00:00'
declare @edate datetime='2017-7-31 00:00'

insert into #dates
select 
    DATEADD(d,number,@sdate)
    ,row_number() over (order by  (select null)) as RN
from 
    master..spt_values 
where 
    type='P' 
    and number<=datediff(d,@sdate,@edate)

declare @numOfDays int = (select count(*) from #dates)



----------------------------------------------------------
--Populate Test Data
----------------------------------------------------------
if object_id('tempdb..#testTable') is not null 
drop table #testTable

create table #testTable([Name] varchar(64), 
                        [Value] decimal (16,4),
                        DT datetime)


insert into #testTable ([Name],[Value],DT)
select
    'Budget'
    ,r.randomNumber
    ,d.d
from
    #dates d
inner join
(SELECT TOP (select @numOfDays) 
    randomNumber,
    row_number() over (order by (select null)) as RN
FROM (
    SELECT CAST(ABS(CAST(NEWID() AS binary(6)) %100000) + RAND() AS DECIMAL (16,4)) + 1  randomNumber
    FROM sysobjects) sample
    GROUP BY randomNumber
    ORDER BY randomNumber DESC) r on r.RN = d.RN

union all

select
    'Not The Budget'
    ,r.randomNumber
    ,d.d
from
    #dates d
inner join
(SELECT TOP (select @numOfDays) 
    randomNumber,
    row_number() over (order by (select null)) as RN
FROM (
    SELECT CAST(ABS(CAST(NEWID() AS binary(6)) %100000) + RAND() AS DECIMAL (16,4)) + 1  randomNumber
    FROM sysobjects) sample
    GROUP BY randomNumber
    ORDER BY randomNumber DESC) r on r.RN = d.RN




----------------------------------------------------------
--Instead of making your variables "dynamic" which
--would likely consist of some loop, just pass in the
--month you care about and let SQL do the work
----------------------------------------------------------


declare @month datetime = '2016-03-31' 

select 
    DT
    ,[Value]
    ,[Name]
    ,sum(case when [Name] = 'Budget' 
                                    then [Value] + 
                                                (([Value] / (DATEDIFF(day,DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @month), 0),@month))) 
                                                *  
                                                (DATEDIFF(DAY,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @month)-1, 0),DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, @month)-1, -1))))  end) as Budget
from 
    #testTable
where
    DT >= DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, @month), 0) --this is Jan 1 of the year associated with your vairable
group by 
    DT
    ,[Name]
    ,[Value]
```